# Is it possible to hide missing characters of typefaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say this is my website:

```css
* {
  font-family: Papyrus, nothing;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Qui legit haec est mirabilis ❤
```

Now, the `❤` is not written in Papyrus, because it's no glyph of this font. I would like to generally hide all glyphs that do not exist in the font file. Taking the `notdef` glyph of the font file instead would be also fine. I want to use it for an editable text area later. So doing it manually doesn't help me.

How is it possible to do that?

Comment: It's not possible with only HTML and CSS but you can use JavaScript to detect this.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the HTML and CSS tags. But still have no idea how to do it ...

Comment: Your welcome! Maybe the CSS tag could stay but not sure the HTML tag needs to stick around. I think using a `@font-face` to embed a fallback would be better than "hiding" the text as it would work in all browsers. I'll try to spin something up and post an answer.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe generating a font file with just empty fields? Or a if function that hides everything that is written in the alternative font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Adobe Blank](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/adobe-blank) as the fallback value in the `font-family` declaration. This way, any glyphs not in the Papyrus font won't be rendered on the page.

```css
* {
  font-family: Papyrus, "Adobe Blank";
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Include the Adobe Blank Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://fontlibrary.org/face/adobe-blank" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<p>Qui legit haec est mirabilis ❤</p>
<p>Qui legit haec est mirabilis❤</p>
```

Comment: @Anna_B This is start. Also so I understand better, when you say an editable text area, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I want something like here: https://www.myfonts.com/sans-serif-fonts – and if somebody types in a glyph that does not exist, it just not should be visible. Your way won't work for it unfortunately ...

Comment: Hmm okay. So adding `<span>` tags is not feasible because you want the user to type text into a `<p>` tag or wherever on the page and the non-glyph characters to not be visible.  Let me think and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: @Anna_B I see what you mean on [myfonts.com](https://www.myfonts.com/sans-serif-fonts). When I type in the heart glyph it shows a box that says "no-glyph". You would like that to happen but for the text not be visible on the page right?

Comment: Yes, that would be great!

Comment: @Anna_B Try this out. I think I've cracked the code by using the Adobe Blank font as the fallback which will make it so any glyphs not supported by Papyrus aren't displayed on the page.

Comment: Your welcome!! I'm glad we were able to get it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't Know That's Possible or not
but you can try this Which will print your emoji
and if you have many emojis then you can create a common class
and then you can do select normal font to print all emoji

```css
* {
  font-family: Papyrus, nothing;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Qui legit haec est mirabilis <span style="Calibri"> ❤
</span>
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't help me. I need this function for editable text areas. Would it be possible for you to delete your answer please? Thanks!

Comment: ok I'll delete but can you explain what you want

Comment: @GlossyPower There's no need to delete. Just edit it and you'll be ok! :)

Comment: It's pretty clear. The OP wants the characters not written in Papyrus to be hidden since it's not a glyph in the font file.

Comment: @Anna_B i got an idea that you can create different span for emoji and create emoji selector reffering this https://codepen.io/lufutu/pen/gWygjW and you can set that selected emoji should go to span